# WP8.1 App: HRESULT E_FAIL crash when scrolling with touch events in emulator

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-emulator

I'm completely clueless about this one ...

In my **WP8.1 app** project I have a `ScrollViewer`, which used to work without problems. After not having used the projects for a few weeks, all of a sudden the app is crashing with a

```
COMException: "HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component. 
at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Control.OnPointerMoved"
```

Strangely this only happens when **using the touchpad for scrolling in the emulator**, it does not happen when I use the mouse for scrolling in the emulator or when I run the app on a device. I thought it might have something to do with the version of Visual Studio, but it both happens in VS 2013 and VS 2015.

It's extremely inconvenient to not being able to work with touch in the emulator, and as said this behaviour just appeared out of the blue, having worked for months, and without changes to the code suddenly behaving like this.

Does anyone have a clue what is going on and how to solve it?